# Contact last-modified date changed by read-only user

Tags: field-level-security, roles, userrecordaccess

Have a number of read only users, that appear to all be setup the same way, though one of the users is somehow being logged as the user for the last-modified date on the contact. Again, checked the user configs and as far as I am able to tell, they're exactly the same except for the user related data such as Name, Alias, Email, Username, Nickname, etc.

Any suggestions about how to track down both what Salesforce believes was changed, and why this user, and only this user is being logged to the last-modified date on contacts?

---

**UPDATE:** Finally, after clicking around, and around, I found something, and in fact, appears to be something that the answer below might have suggested as the source; though indirectly, sense it appears to be code from the NPSP that's the source of the issue. Selected the answer below as the answer, and posted a new question here: [How to find/stop/disable Apex Jobs that a read-only user has activated](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36721/how-to-find-stop-disable-apex-jobs-that-a-read-only-user-has-activated)

Comment: To get to the bottom of this issue, you will need to recreate the problem. Judging by the comments under one of the answers here, you don't know exactly when this is happening for sure, and so it's going to be difficult to solve. If you can come up with some steps that consistently cause the update, we will be closer to the answer. Also, do you have any third-party apps installed, other than the Non-Profit Starter Pack?

Comment: @JeremyNottingham: No, nothing else has been installed by me on SF, and I'm the only non-read-only user currently; this is going to change, but at this point, troubled that somehow a read-only user was able to be logged as doing something. As for the timing, believe I've got it down to an exact time, but no event to tie it to; 1000s of contacts were had their last-mod-date updated within 2-minutes on May 20th, though it was not all the records. If you have any questions or suggestions, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: My only suggestion at this point is to try to get a sequence of steps that causes this to happen, and then observe the process. You still don't know when it's happening, so you won't be able to determine why.

Comment: @JeremyNottingham: Meaning that unless the user is able to roughly recall what they did and reproduce it, then there's zero info logged in SF by default on EE that might give a clue to how/why 1000s of files now have a last-mod-date updated to the user's name, right, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In no particular order...

- Time-based workflows with one of these guys as "default running user"?
- batch jobs scheduled as one of these guys (Apex will run in system mode and unless the code explicitly checks the permissions - "impossible is nothing").
- Integrations? Check the users' login history maybe? Pay attention to IP, login times, the application type...
- Sites? Do you have anything exposed as Web-to-Lead for example?
- Inbound email handlers configured to run under this user?
- Do you use "Salesforce to Salesforce"?

As for tracking...

- deactivate them and wait for fireworks :P
- setup field history tracking on fields you consider important?

Comment: Thank you; just checked, and none the reasons listed appear to apply to me, it might help someone else if they happen to run across this. All the current contacts were bulk loaded; it's a single user; noting unusual in the access logs; beyond being given a read-only user (Profile = Read Only); their user has not been used for anything else by me, the only non-read-only user currently; bit at a loss, and it's concerning that a read-only user is being listed as doing something and neither they or I have any reason to believe they're "modified" anything.

Comment: Any rate, thanks, and if you have any other suggestions, just post a comment so that I'm aware of anything you post; updates to the answer won't ping me for some reason.

Comment: Most interesting. How about setting up a workflow rule + email alert "every time record is created or edited" to yourself, make the workflow's firing condition a formula with value of 'true'?

Comment: Aside from a ping that something happened, would the change (before & after) be listed in the email with the user's name and the record-id? If not, might be useful, though not exactly sure how much additional information it might give to track down what is going on. Thanks!

Comment: Make your workflow only fire when it's that particular user that is `LastModifiedBy`, and then look at the exact times this happens. If it's a regular occurrence, you may see patterns that help identify what's going on.

Comment: @JeremyNottingham: Might be wrong, but it appears to happen whenever the user opens a contact; meaning I was training a group of users (which include the user in question), another user noticed that the last modified date had changed, I confirmed the user was read-only, manual confirmed it didn't appear the user in question wasn't able to edit at least fields I attempted to edit, and it appeared that any recorded they viewed then became marked as last modified by them. Meaning the pattern is them opening any contact, and appears to be unrelated to the timing; possible I am missing something.

Comment: Maybe you have an embedded Visualforce page or other integration? Just because they can't modify a record normally doesn't mean a "without sharing" class decides to modify the record.

Comment: @sfdcfox: First, if it's not clear, I have a very limited knowledge of SF; this is not to say that I'm not open to suggestions. So, guess my assumption is that the SF instance I have is an EE using the NPSP packages, there were 8+ users signed in using the default read-only SF profile, and only one was flagging reads as being modified by them. Aside from bulk loading some data, adding a few custom fields, having SF switch the account from trial to non-trial, I've done nothing else.

Comment: Possible the issue is with the profile, but I've compared the profile by opening other profiles and clicking back and forth, and there is zero difference. Happy to load any data, pics, etc into the answer, just don't know what would be of use.

Comment: Leads or Contacts? Leads have 1 special field: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11464/leads-unread-by-owner-workflow-on-this-field. If it kicks in only the first time he views this record then it might be valid...

Comment: @eyescream: There are no leads. Also, did a little more digging, and it appears the user logged in yesterday, but no records were modified. It appears all the records were modified on May 20th from 11:45-46 AM, and it was a lot of records, meaning nothing that could have been done manually opening up a single record, by single record; meaning roughly 35k in records were listed with a new mod date, and the only mod dates in the system are from my bulk loads and that user's mod-dates at that time.

Comment: Might attempt to do a diff of the weekly backup I did before the event to what in SF currently, but from my perspective, this is very strange, meaning to me, read-only means, read-only, and if it does not, that role should not be called read-only... :-)

Comment: For standard pages & API access it does. But the moment you write JS (Ajax toolkit) or Apex code - it becomes your responsibility to protect it. You can hide buttons by page layouts, revoke access to VF pages and classes... But your code should still have checks like http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10532/finding-if-a-custom-field-is-editable-using-apex-code

Comment: Sorry for spam... You've checked the Profile, cool. Does the user have any permission sets assigned on top of it though? Does he see the "Edit" button on Contact (he shouldn't if it's real Readonly profile). Does he get "insufficient privileges" error when he force navigates to `/someContactsId/e`?

Comment: To test with the user in question, I'd have to takeover there account, since they normally work remotely, but I did just test `/someContactsId/e` with a test account that should have the exact same profile/access/etc and it returned an "Insufficient Privileges" msg. Permission Set Assignments under the user in question states "No records to display."

Comment: Finally, after clicking around, and around, I found something, and in fact, appears to be something you might have suggested as the source. Selected your answer above as the answer, and posted a new question here: [How to find/stop/disable Apex Jobs that a read-only user has activated](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36721/how-to-find-stop-disable-apex-jobs-that-a-read-only-user-has-activated)