# How do I secure the Nonprofit Starter Pack from the Salesforce Foundation?

Tags: security, profile, npsp

So, it appears that I did not lock-down the Nonprofit Starter Pack (NPSP) from the Salesforce Foundation (SFF) as well as I should, and attempting to avoid issues like this in the future. Looking for suggestions on how to search the NPSP for possible "[privilege escalation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation)" that would allow a read-only user to do anything beyond read-only actions; for an example of where things went wrong, [see this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/36748/7651).

Also, beyond the NPSP, for the read-only user profile only, is there anything else within the default EE+NPSP install that I should lock-down?

If if matters, currently beyond the default EE+NPSP install, nothing else has been installed.

Comment: I wanted to provide some clarification on the "privilege escalation" you refer to.  What appears to have happened is that you had a read only user profile who was allowed access to the Recurring Donations Settings tab.  Any user allowed to access that tab can click a button to trigger a batch job.  The batch job code is secured as part of the managed package and the job itself is isolated in what it does.  This is not a case of a read only user being able to modify any data but rather a read only user being able to trigger a rather harmless batch process.

Comment: @Jason Lantz: I'd be the first to admit that I have a very limited understanding of the topic, but to my knowledge, read-only does not include being able to execute anything that results in data being modified, regardless of if it is "harmless" or not. In this case, this "harmless" act resulted in hours of work to find & stop the issue and over 70% of the records being updated with a username that should not have been able to update any records, which doesn't sound harmless to me, since the updates over wrote valid exist modification dates to reflect null being switched to zero via that user.

Comment: @JasonLantz: If possible, please comment on this question, which also relates to securing the NPSP, "[How do you do a Security Source Scan of managed or unmanaged packages?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/37083/how-do-you-do-a-security-source-scan-of-managed-or-unmanaged-packages#comment50468_37084)" - thanks!

Comment: My point is that this is not a major security hole in the NPSP as you've implied.  The batch job is a normal process which runs in the NPSP whether triggered by an admin or a read only user granted access to the settings tab in their profile.  The job does not run under the permissions of the triggering user.  The batch job will regularly update your contacts and that will in turn update the LastModifiedDate and LastModifiedBy fields.  Thus, the new last modified values are indeed valid values as the object was updated by the batch job.

Comment: @JasonLantz: Never implied anything, other than what happened, which to my knowledge was acknowledged by the NPSP dev team as being an issue. To me, read-only means read-only, any updates executed by a read-only user are invalid in my opinion; to say otherwise might be seen as being argumentative. Further, there are no batch jobs that result in updates that are available for execution by read-only users in the default EE build, and I have no reason to believe that this is not by design; meaning EE code blocks read-only users from executing batch jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sfdcfox commented under [How to find/stop/disable Apex Jobs that a read-only user has activated](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36721/how-to) - start with revoking access to VF pages responsible for this mess, especially the configuration-like ones. There might be valid pages that allow them to run some report-like functionality for example (ideally they'd be marked as `<apex:page readonly="true">` though). But as I wrote in your 1st question - all custom Apex and JS that uses API is the developer's responsibility to secure. Plus triggers run in system mode too so if there is something else that needs to have a side effect in related contacts... You know the drill.

You could hide tabs (if these are tabs) by Profile but user that knows the URL can still reach the page. So treat them as security holes until you've checked whether they're harmless on Githhub ;) Also - you could always fork the repo, add proper security checks and ask the team lead to include them!

Another idea is to add a validation rule on Contact, something along `$Profile.Name = 'ReadOnly'` and message "bugger off" ;) Although if you'll do it probably it's better to do it by Profile Id and not name as name can be translated to other languages. Or if these users share a Role - I don't think roles are translated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably best to transition to Permission Sets. Then give every user a zero-permission profile and just layer PermSets on top.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Is this a good guide, or is there something better? [Salesforce Security Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_security/)

Comment: Best guide is salesforcehacker.com - dude knows this inside and out.